# What maximum number of buttons i can connect to Arduino (100 buttons and more)

Tags: arduino

Is it possible to connect something like 100 buttons to one arduino nano, by using this classic method (or other possible cases)?
[image]

Comment: Yes.possible. I2C IO expander. Tonnes of.

Comment: @Umar What ohm nominal i need to use? Can i use similar nominal for all resistors?

Comment: A proper schematic would be preferable. Is it a technique where the various buttons each connect the ADC input to a different point of a resistor string, a bit like a pot? Then, the answer mostly depends on the ADC accuracy and your resistors precision, but 100 buttons with this technique is asking for trouble. Charlieplexing, ase @Pete suggested, is a much better option.

Comment: You can connect any number of buttons through a serial interface. For example, you could use two GPIO pins to bit-bang the PS2 interface and connect a standard  104-key (or more) keyboard.

Comment: Can you please post this as a schematic?  The fritzing is very hard to follow.

Comment: In case of LEDs, charlieplex works fine even for glowing multiple LEDs at a time due to persistence of vision. But, for multiple buttons to be detected at a time as active is not eww easy and may be impossible

Answer (score 3):

**"Is it possible to connect something like 100 buttons to one arduino nano, by using this classic method (or other possible cases)? "**

Yes. to connect more than 100 inputs you can Charlieplex 11 of the arduino uno input buttons (this will actually give more than 100 inputs,110 to be exact) . This requires no extra ICs to do. Just still using resistors,diodes and more than 100 input buttons-using 11 arduino uno digital inputs.

If you want to use IC you can bitbang the 100 inputs using shiftin() see https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ShiftIn

PS2 keyboard (As Dave Tweedy suggested) is less flexible regarding scalibility (eg if you want 200 inputs you just daisy chain some IC together) and probably more programming work than using the IC method above.

Comment: and what ohm nominal i need to use? Can i use similar nominal for all resistors?

Comment: you will need 11 resistors, between 11k ohm  to 20k ohm

Comment: So they all similar or different? I just want to understand for myself how many of them I need to buy.

Comment: the can all be the same value ohm-11 required

Comment: is it ok to use method which is here http://tronixstuff.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/example25p21.jpg

Comment: thats a different method -not charlieplexing- using analog input. It a different way to answer your question

Comment: If you dont understand electronics well then go for charlieplexing-its easier to do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51182/discussion-between-fonjeekay-and-pete).

Comment: @Pete you should show a schematic to explain how to charliexplex buttons. And there needs to be diodes, which you didn't mention. Here is a useful [link](http://www.pcbheaven.com/wikipages/Charlieplexing/), scroll down to "Charlieplexing also to interface buttons". And another [explanation](http://www.mosaic-industries.com/embedded-systems/microcontroller-projects/electronic-circuits/matrix-keypad-scan-decode), which has nice schematics.

Comment: @dim I dont know how to draw schematics on my computer-diodes are required -answer updated-but it would still be cheaper than an IC for 100 buttons

Comment: @Pete Yes, I agree it's probably the best solution, indeed. I just suggested to improve your answer by including all information... So that I can eventually upvote. You can draw schematics by clicking on the corresponding icon on the toolbar, when you edit your post. Or you can include any image (e.g. a non-copyrighted schematic you find on the internet), which is even easier.

Answer (score 1):

This implementation is possible but you should take care of,

1. The range of ADC readings corresponding to each button activity.
2. Choosing the proper values of resistance so that none of them would result in the conflicting range of ADC reading.
3. Choosing the resistance values with better tolerance value is most important.